# ViewModels members not updated on Command

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I'm using MVVM light toolkit to handle a button click. If I do:

```
CustomerSaveCommand = new RelayCommand(
    () => CustomerSave(),
    ()=> true);

private void CustomerSave() {
    customer.Address="My Street";
}
```

The function is invoked but the Address field bound in the UI is not updated.

If I put `customer.Address="1234"` in the ViewModel constructor, the UI IS updated. What am I doing wrong?

EDITED:

The problem is really strange: if I do `viewModel.customer.City = "CITY1"` in the window load it runs, if I add a button and, in the code-behind click, I add `viewModel.customer.City = "CITY2"` it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The customer object in your viewmodel needs to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.

Then in the Address Property setter, you would invoke the PropertyChanged event.

Alternatively, your viewModel can implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, and could wrap the Address property and call the PropertyChanged event. You would have to update your bindings, but your model objects wouldn't have to implement any interfaces.

The reason you're seeing that the address is showing up when you modify the object in the constructor is because binding has not taken place yet. In order for the UI to be updated you need to instruct the binding engine that a property binding has changed. To do that you use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explaination: i actually have public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private Customer _customer;
        public Customer customer 
        {
            get { return _customer; }
            set
            {
                _customer = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("customer");
            }
        } 
}
 isn't that enough to do databinding? I hoped not to have to NotifyPropertyChanged for every single record.

Comment: Cris, you need to RaisePropertyChanged("Address"); for the Address property in the Customer class. Otherwise, you need to create a new property on your ViewModel called "Address" that looks like this: public String Address { get { return customer.Address; } set { _customer.Address = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Address"); } } that your UI binds to, instead of the customer object directly.

Comment: The Customer class is autogenerated by EntityFramework ,so i think it is not good to modify it. In effects, if i create a single Address property it runs fine, as you said. I hoped to directly bind a single db record using the customer object.

Comment: @Cris   
I think the Customer class that gets auto-generated by EntityFramework is actually a partial class, so you can just define another partial Customer class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and define your address property there. See Partial Classes for more information.

Comment: @Cris However, using the partial class trick will result in two Address properties which is also kind of crappy. So, instead, you may want to use EntityFramework's [T4 Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx) to define how the Address property should be auto-generated (i.e. implement INotifyPropertyChanged).

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
    public class AutoDelegateCommand : RelayCommand, ICommand
{
    public AutoDelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : base(execute)
    {
    }

    public AutoDelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        : base(execute, canExecute)
    {
    }

    event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it must be something different and strange:  if i do viewModel.customer.City = "CITY1"; in the window_load it runs, if i add a button and, in the code-behind click i add viewModel.customer.City = "CITY2"; it does not work.